# Multi-platform 2D graphics in Java

Tags: java, graphics, cross-platform, 2d

What is the best approach for high-performance 2D graphics on multiple platforms (at least Windows and Android devices)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GO with OpenGL multi platform one